# Default Directory of NSKeyedArchiver

Tags: iphone, nskeyedarchiver

I'm using NSKeyedArchiver to save an object. I didn't write out a full path in the path argument so my file is being written somewhere in the Apple iPhone simulator.

What directory is my file going to?

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:self toFile:@"Vanilla"];
```

Thanks!

mj

Comment: Why don't you wrote a full path? I'm not even sure that it will work without a valid path...

Comment: It works fine :). I can read in and out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was writing it to root "/".
 mj